# How to deserialize oriented bounding box

Tags: unity-game-engine, bounding-box

I want to import meshes from http://www.scenenn.net/ into Unity. Each mesh is a 3D scan of a room and comes with an xml annotation file. Each entry in the annotation contains an oriented bounding box enclosing an object. This is how the data is stored:

```
<label ... obbox="0.996832 0.578123 -3.63623 0.143642 0.0413364 0.0202401 0.735559 0.00222934 -0.0116653 0.677357" />
```

The paper describes those values as follows:

> Oriented Bounding Box (OBB). For each object, the eigenvectors of its vertices are used to define an oriented bounding box which tightly encloses the object.

My question is - how do I convert those 10 floats into bounding box in Unity coordinates?

Comment: I did not get why they used this OBB but imo you do not need it since you will be using Unity. As long as you have the coordinates and faces you can construct your meshes in Unity. Unity already calculates the bounding box itself when you create meshes.  You can check [Free Point Cloud Viewer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/point-cloud-free-viewer-19811) asset to give you an idea. This is only for point clouds but you can modify it to triangulate your meshes as well.

Comment: @AliKanat the mesh they provide is a single mesh of an entire room with every object in it that resulted from 3D scan. As far as I understand it, they manually labeled vertices/faces of this mesh as belonging to a certain object (desks, chairs, etc). The mesh is provided in .ply file if that matters

Comment: So you need the meshes separately? I did not try to  open the .ply files since they are binaries.